# What performance we get with same data combines with different datasets?

Tags: classification, cross-entropy

Suppose that we have dataset of special kind of cat. We are going to train a model on combination of the cat a the car! Suppose that in this model we will get a performance ( precision,recall or...) X for the cats.
Now suppose we combine the cats with a dataset of another species of cat.
The question is,do we get the same performance X for the second model?

Comment: _of the cat a the car_ ??

Comment: also, you have no guarantee on what your model might perform on the other dataset... overfitting might lead to 100% accuracy for the first one, and maybe with the second dataset, since will be larger, the model can't actually memorize everything, leading to an accuracy less than 100%

Comment: With the cat. Because cats are the same in both datasets.

Comment: Why I ask this question is that, when we have thousands of labels, does each label have negative effect on other labels due to the cross entropy?

Comment: no, you can train a different classifier for each label, nobody will stop you from doing that... however, this often leads to overfitting and unbalanced datasets (or thousands of classifiers), which is not idea... so what usually is done, if your method permits multiple outcomes, like NN, you use multitask learning as a form of both regularization and to have a single classifier for the whole problem

Comment: So, I think when we have the [cat,car], we do not need a complicated network, however, when we have [cat type1, cat type2] we need the complicated one.

Comment: that's absolutely not true, there is no way that you can assess that, and it might completely depends on what dataset you have access to.